# sort on a vector of pointers changes data in a copy of the vector?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, stl, shared-ptr

I have a vector of pointers to objects, and at some point, making a second vector with sub-elements of that vector. Now, sorting the original vector changes the elements in the second vector (there are completely different elements in it after the sort).

Is this expected behaviour? Does it have something to do with make_indirect_iterator?
Is there a better solution to it (assuming I want to keep a vector of pointers)?

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyObj>> vecAll;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyObj>> vecSub;

// fill vecAll with something...

for(auto obj : vecAll) {
    if( obj->x >=0 ) {
        vecSub.push_back(obj);
    }
}

// 3 objects in 'vecSub'

std::sort(boost::make_indirect_iterator(vecAll.begin()), boost::make_indirect_iterator(vecAll.end()), std::greater<MyObj>());

// now there are 3 DIFFERENT objects in 'vecSub'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's related to `make_indirect_iterator`.  That causes object values to be swapped, instead of just reordering the pointers.

You could instead use normal iterators and perform the dereference in the comparison step.  Lambdas make that easier:

```
typedef decltype(vecAll.front()) iter;
std::sort(vecAll.begin(),
          vecAll.end(),
          [](iter a, iter b) { return *a > *b; });
```

Version with a reusable functor (thanks MooingDuck for the suggestion):

```
struct indirect_greater
{
    template<typename iter>
    bool operator()(iter a, iter b) const { return *a > *b; }
};

std::sort(vecAll.begin(), vecAll.end(), indirect_greater());
```

C++14 adds polymorphic lambdas, which will let you write a short lambda `[](a, b)(*a > *b)` that behaves like the second (functor) solution.  No need to name the iterator type (e.g. with `decltype`).

Comment: One of the places where I think boosts lambdas make things easier to read: `_1 < _2` (assuming they are imported into the namespace).

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Yeah, that looks better.  I did just improve readability of my solution a fair amount, but it's still not as good as the boost lambda.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Hmm okay, that doesn't look too bad. However, I'm using the sort at several places in the code, so that would mean I'd have to write the same lambda (and decltype) every time I want to sort that vector. That smells like bad code repetition to me, doesn't it?

Comment: @Ela782: You could move it into a functionoid easily enough: `struct indirect_less{bool operator(iter a, iter b) { return *a > *b; }};`

Comment: @MooingDuck: Close, but perhaps `struct indirect_greater{ template<typename iter> bool operator()(iter a, iter b) { return *a > *b; }};`

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks Mooing Duck.
Is there any reason for why make_indirect_iterator does not behave as expected?

Comment: @Ela782: It's because `std::sort` does two operations on elements -- comparison and swapping, and when you use indirect iterators, they affect *both*.  But you really want to deal with the value for comparison, but the pointer for swapping purposes.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for elaborating on that (and for updating your solution). Perfect answer!